# Data export from Excel to CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv

When I transferred the data from separated columns and rows from my excel sheet to .csv format, it does not separate the data in .csv format. I am putting my code below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lastrow As Long, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wbDest As Workbook, _
        wsDest As Worksheet, path As String

    If ComboBox1.Value = "DENİZBANK - ALTUNİZADE ŞUBE" Then
        'Combobox isimli bir dosya aç
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("TL")
        path = "C:\Users\emir.DEMTA\Desktop\Vahit Çağlayan Dosyalar\p. CSV\DENİZBANK - ALTUNİZADE ŞUBE\Deniz_Giden_Banka_HGS.csv"
        Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(path)
        Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Deniz_Giden_Banka_HGS")
        n = 1

        For i = 13 To 50 'lastrow
            'Aşağıdaki verileri combobox isimli dosyaya yazdır.
            If ComboBox1.Value = "DENİZBANK - ALTUNİZADE ŞUBE" And _
               ComboBox5.Value = "1073196-389" And _
               TextBox5.Value <> "" And _
               ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = "DENİZBANK - ALTUNİZADE ŞUBE" And _
               ws.Cells(i, "I").Value = "Banka" Then
                wsDest.Cells(n + 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value
                wsDest.Cells(n + 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
                wsDest.Cells(n + 1, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
                wsDest.Cells(n + 1, 5) = "1"
                wsDest.Cells(n + 1, 6) = "'01"
                wsDest.Cells(n + 1, 7) = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
                wsDest.Cells(n + 1, 8) = ws.Cells(i, 8).Value

                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next i

        wbDest.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\emir.DEMTA\Desktop\Vahit Çağlayan Dosyalar\p. CSV\DENİZBANK - ALTUNİZADE ŞUBE\" _
           & " D - HGS - " & Date & ".csv"
        wbDest.Close
        Set wbDest = Nothing

        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

Every information in the Excel transferred to .csv occurred alongside in one cell

```
MasrafHGS100
```

What I want is to transfer all the data the same of at my code

```
Masraf    HGS    100
```

Comment: If you `.SaveAs` you also need to specify the `FileFormat:=` according the [XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) in your case probably `FileFormat:=xlCSV`. Then open the CSV in a text editor to check it! Not in Excel. If you open it in Excel, it does a CSV to Excel import (if that has the wrong porperties it does not import it correctly into different columns). Note that a double click on a .CSV file (that opens it in Excel) is a lucky shot and no proper import! It might show up as expected or not.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and for your comment @Pᴇʜ.

I am sharing with you my solution below.

 ```
                With wbDest
                    wbDest.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True, Filename:="C:\Users\emir.DEMTA\Desktop\Vahit Çağlayan Dosyalar\p. CSV\DENİZBANK - ALTUNİZADE ŞUBE\" _
                    & " D - HGS - " & Date & ".csv"
                    wbDest.Close False
                    Set wbDest = Nothing
                    Set wsDest = Nothing
                End With
                   End If
 ```

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `.SaveAs` you also need to specify the `FileFormat:=` according the [XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) in your case probably `FileFormat:=xlCSV`. Then open the CSV in a text editor to check it! Not in Excel.

If you open it in Excel, it does a CSV to Excel import (if that has the wrong porperties it does not import it correctly into different columns). Note that a double click on a .CSV file (that opens it in Excel) is a lucky shot and no proper import! It might show up as expected or not.

```
wbDest.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True, Filename:="C:\Users\emir.DEMTA\Desktop\Vahit Çağlayan Dosyalar\p. CSV\DENİZBANK - ALTUNİZADE ŞUBE\" _ & " D - HGS - " & Date & ".csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you're just specifying that the file ends with `.csv`. However that does not apply the "format" of a CSV file.

To do that you need to always specify when you do a
`.SaveAs` Name - FileFormat
You can do `FileFormat:=xlCSV` or `FileFormat:=6`

Alternatively, you can always do a `FileFormat:=xlTextWindows` to get a `.txt` file and then transform it to a `.csv` using an alternative method.